# Are sig_atomic_t and std::atomic<> interchangable?

Tags: c++, signals, atomic

As per the title. Can I use `std::atomic<>` in a signal handler or does `sig_atomic_t` provide other compiler features?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

n3376 1.9/6

> When the processing of the abstract machine is interrupted by receipt of a signal, the values of objects which
> are neither
>
> — of type volatile std::sig_atomic_t nor
>
> — lock-free atomic objects (29.4)
>
> are unspecified during the execution of the signal handler, and the value of any object not in either of
> these two categories that is modified by the handler becomes undefined.

Lock-free 29.4/1,2

> The ATOMIC_..._LOCK_FREE macros indicate the lock-free property of the corresponding atomic types, with
> the signed and unsigned variants grouped together. The properties also apply to the corresponding (partial)
> specializations of the atomic template. A value of 0 indicates that the types are never lock-free. A value of
> 1 indicates that the types are sometimes lock-free. A value of 2 indicates that the types are always lock-free.
>
> The function **atomic_is_lock_free** (29.6) indicates whether the object is lock-free. In any given program
> execution, the result of the lock-free query shall be consistent for all pointers of the same type.

Comment: For completeness, that means you can use a `std::atomic<T> x;` variable *if* `x.is_lock_free()` is true.