# volatile, std::sig_atomic_t, and atomic_signal_fence

Tags: c++, c++11

Example

```
#include <csignal>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

volatile std::sig_atomic_t gSignalStatus = 0;

void signal_handler(int signal) {
    gSignalStatus = signal;
}

int main() {
    // Install a signal handler
    std::signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler);

    while (gSignalStatus == 0) {}
    printf("%d\n", gSignalStatus);
}
```

I am trying to understand few things:

1. Is it even correct to declare a variable with a type of `std::sig_atomic_t` without `volatile`?  Given the variable is shared between the handler and a thread -- just like `gSignalStatus` above but without `volatile`.  According to the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518902/exactly-which-variables-need-to-be-sig-atomic-t-in-the-context-of-signal-handlin), it seems `volatile` is required.
2. According to C++ standard:

   > extern "C" void atomic_signal_fence(memory_order order) noexcept;
   >   6 Effects: Equivalent to atomic_thread_fence(order), except that the resulting ordering constraints
   >   are established only between a thread and a signal handler executed in the same thread.

it sounds like the specification assumes the signal handler can be called by any thread and so `atomic_signal_fence` is added to the spec?  But the quoted spec above also mentions "same thread".  Hence, I am confused.  Tho, on my machine, the signal handler is called by the main thread.  An example to illustrate the need of `atomic_signal_fence` would be nice too!

Thanks!

Comment: `volatile` is unrelated to multi-threading.

Comment: Note that the question you linked is regarding C and referencing the C standard, while your question is tagged C++ and is clearly C++ code. I can't say whether C and C++ are the same in this situation, but there's a good chance they are not.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes.  `volatile` is to tell compiler that the variable might be changed in a way not defined in the standard.  But the C++ spec just mentions `volatile std::sig_atomic_t` once without stating whether `volatile` is necessary or `std::sig_atomic_t` alone is implicitly containing `volatile` or `std::sig_atomic_t` alone will likely have undefined behavior, etc.

Comment: @FredLarson yes, my question is for C++ not C.  I linked to a post with a quote from C99 standard.  I know it isn't exactly related but C++ standard doesn't say much about `std::sig_atomic_t` with `volatile`; hence, I just tried to associate my question with C standard to see if it is implied or some sort.

Comment: `std::atomic<int> gSignalStatus = 0;` is the right way.

Comment: The [cppreference page on `sig_atomic_t` for C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/sig_atomic_t) is interesting but overly terse, it would seem.

Comment: @Jarod42 based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949036/are-sig-atomic-t-and-stdatomic-interchangable), it seems like `std::sig_atomic_t` can't be replaced by `std::atomic` in some case (of course, if the template parameter is `int`, they are interchangeable), but it also seems that `std::sig_atomic_t` is the preferred type to be used in signal handler, no?

Comment: From your link, `volatile` is required for `sig_atomic_t` in case of signal "handling".

Comment: [`std::signal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal) has a lot of helpful bits about changes to usage between C++ revisions.

Comment: FredLarson jon-harper thanks for the links.  If I recall correctly, people on stackoverflow found various mistakes on cppreference.com; so it is just not a trusted source at least to me. lol

Answer (score 0):

In your particular use case it may be more power efficient and appropriate to use [`sigwait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigwait.3.html) function. No `volatile` or `std::atomic` is necessary.

Comment: Agree.  The example is just for illustration.  My main goal is trying to find answers for the 2 questions I asked so that I can correctly and efficiently use std::signal.  In my real application, my main thread is running a tight loop to do work and will do clean up and exit the loop if SIGTERM is detected.